How to Use a tsfresh Feature Calculator with Results from Another Feature Calculator
When using the tsfresh library for feature extraction, is it possible to run a feature calculator that takes the results of another feature calculator as its parameters?
For instance, I want to calculate (or approximate) the frequency of my signal. Specifically, I would like to use the number_crossing_m(x, m) feature calculator, which determines the number of times x crosses m. My goal is to calculate the number of crossings of x at the mean value of x, which requires using another feature calculator.
